# Can Boost 1.65.x be used with Visual C++ 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, boost

I got the Boost 64-bit Windows Installer for VC++ 2010 (boost_1_65_0-msvc-10.0-64.exe) from https://sourceforge.net/projects/boost/files/boost-binaries/1.65.0/.

The Include and Library path settings in the project are correct.

Trying to use it in a x64 Console project results in several build errors - I am only using the thread class here. These are the errors I get:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: CPSS, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
1>  stdafx.cpp
1>  SockServer.cpp
1>  Linking to lib file: libboost_thread-vc100-mt-gd-1_65.lib
1>  Linking to lib file: libboost_date_time-vc100-mt-gd-1_65.lib
1>  Linking to lib file: libboost_system-vc100-mt-gd-1_65.lib
1>E:\hld\Src\Boost\boost_1_65_0\boost/system/error_code.hpp(255): warning C4355: 'this' : used in base member initializer list
1>  Linking to lib file: libboost_chrono-vc100-mt-gd-1_65.lib
1>  CPSS.cpp
1>  Linking to lib file: libboost_thread-vc100-mt-gd-1_65.lib
1>  Linking to lib file: libboost_date_time-vc100-mt-gd-1_65.lib
1>  Linking to lib file: libboost_system-vc100-mt-gd-1_65.lib
1>E:\hld\Src\Boost\boost_1_65_0\boost/system/error_code.hpp(255): warning C4355: 'this' : used in base member initializer list
1>  Linking to lib file: libboost_chrono-vc100-mt-gd-1_65.lib
1>E:\hld\Src\Boost\boost_1_65_0\boost/thread/detail/thread.hpp(271): error C2752: 'boost::move_detail::remove_reference<T>' : more than one partial specialization matches the template argument list
1>          with
1>          [
1>              T=int (__cdecl &)(void)
1>          ]
1>          E:\hld\Src\Boost\boost_1_65_0\boost/move/detail/meta_utils.hpp(105): could be 'boost::move_detail::remove_reference<T&&>'
1>          E:\hld\Src\Boost\boost_1_65_0\boost/move/detail/meta_utils.hpp(97): or       'boost::move_detail::remove_reference<T&>'
1>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\xxshared(13) : see reference to function template instantiation 'boost::thread::thread<int(__cdecl &)(void)>(F)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              F=int (__cdecl &)(void)
1>          ]
1>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\xxshared(35) : see reference to function template instantiation 'std::tr1::_Ref_count_obj<_Ty>::_Ref_count_obj<int(__cdecl &)(void)>(_Arg0)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty=thread_t,
1>              _Arg0=int (__cdecl &)(void)
1>          ]
1>          CPSS.cpp(34) : see reference to function template instantiation 'std::tr1::shared_ptr<_Ty> std::tr1::make_shared<thread_t,int(__cdecl &)(void)>(_Arg0)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty=thread_t,
1>              _Arg0=int (__cdecl &)(void)
1>          ]
1>E:\hld\Src\Boost\boost_1_65_0\boost/thread/detail/thread.hpp(271): error C2668: 'boost::forward' : ambiguous call to overloaded function
1>          E:\hld\Src\Boost\boost_1_65_0\boost/move/utility_core.hpp(252): could be 'T boost::forward<F>(int (__cdecl &)(void))'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              T=int (__cdecl &)(void),
1>              F=int (__cdecl &)(void)
1>          ]
1>          E:\hld\Src\Boost\boost_1_65_0\boost/move/utility_core.hpp(248): or       'T boost::forward<F>(int (__cdecl &)(void))'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              T=int (__cdecl &)(void),
1>              F=int (__cdecl &)(void)
1>          ]
1>          while trying to match the argument list '(int (__cdecl &)(void))'
1>  SockServerEx.cpp
1>  Linking to lib file: libboost_thread-vc100-mt-gd-1_65.lib
1>  Linking to lib file: libboost_date_time-vc100-mt-gd-1_65.lib
1>  Linking to lib file: libboost_system-vc100-mt-gd-1_65.lib
1>E:\hld\Src\Boost\boost_1_65_0\boost/system/error_code.hpp(255): warning C4355: 'this' : used in base member initializer list
1>  Linking to lib file: libboost_chrono-vc100-mt-gd-1_65.lib
1>  Generating Code...
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm using the nuget package boost-vc100, version 1.65.1.0 on a windows 7, x86 without problems.

Comment: Note that the nuget package requires VS2010 sp1